# spacemacs auto-complete layer: showing the difference between a snippet and a dictionary word

Tags: spacemacs, company-mode, auto-complete-mode

Say, I have been using `Spacemacs` for a while now, and was looking at `Spacevim` a bit. One nice feature of `Spacevim` is that it's autocompletion feature includes both the words for completion as well as snippets. So if I am in `latex` mode, the completion dropdown will display both potential completion text as well as snippet text.

I have include a picture of this below.

[image]

I was wondering if there is a feature like this in Spacemacs or emacs? I know that `Spacemacs` seems to use `company.el` for completion, but was not sure if I could switch to a different completion package and if that would solve the problem? Would something from `helm` be able to provide this?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is [in the spacemacs docs for the auto-completion layer](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Bcompletion/auto-completion#show-snippets-in-auto-completion-popup):

```
(setq auto-completion-enable-snippets-in-popup t)
```

You can read those docs inline with `SPC h l auto-completion RET` (and you can jump to that node using `SPC s j show snippets RET`).

The text in those docs is suggesting that rather than putting that `setq` above in your `dotspacemacs/user-config`, you can have something like this in the `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers` section of your `.spacemacs` file (`SPC f e d` to view it), which I guess is more spacemacs-y:

```
'(javascript
  haskell
  ...
  ivy
  (auto-completion
   :variables
   auto-completion-enable-snippets-in-popup t)
  ;; better-defaults
  emacs-lisp
  ...
```